# Каковы достоинства и недостатки наследования от прототипа в сравнении с наследованием от класса?

Tags: ооп, наследование

Перерыл уже кучу ресурсов, но вот о достоинствах и недостатках ничего не нашел.

Comment: В JS нет наследования на базе классов. Только прототипы, только хардкор

Comment: Это я прекрасно знаю, мне вот нужны достоинства и недостатки прототипов по сравнению с классическим наследованием например в Java, просто рейтинг не позволяет мне оставить более конкретизирующие теги

Comment: Это просто разные вещи, у каждой свои преимущества и свои проблемы. Вы ведь не спрашиваете «чем числа лучше строк?».

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В теории прототипы дают больше гибкости. С их помощью можно вытворять такое, что строгому ООПу и не снилось. Поэтому...

### В теории

#### Преимущества:

- Умопомрачительная гибкость: возможность менять прототипы во время выполнения программы, генерировать динамические иерархии прототипов и совершать прочие забавные вещи.
- Вас не смогут уволить, потому что код сможете поддерживать только вы.

#### Недостатки:

- Ваш код никто не будет понимать.

Однако если вы примените эту теорию на практике, то вас засмеют за ненормальное программирование, а то вовсе попросят на выход. Практически всегда вы будете использовать только те возможности прототипов, которые аккуратно ложатся в ООП. Более того, существующие движки джаваскрипта предполагают, что вы будете использовать строгие "классы", и при уходе в динамику сильно проседают по производительности. Так что переходим к суровой правде жизни...

### На практике

#### Преимущества:

- Отсутствуют.

#### Недостатки:

- Странный синтаксис.
- Зоопарк библиотек, эмулирующих обычные классы.

И будем честны: единственный мейнстримовый язык с прототипами — это JavaScript. Это такой язык, который дизайнили 10 дней и накодили за пару месяцев. В новой версии стандарта вводят синтаксический сахар для классов, поэтому старый синтаксис с прототипами уйдёт в прошлое. Посему...

### В ближайшем будущем

#### Преимущества:

- Если вы знаете, что такое прототипы, то вы будете на 20% круче тех, кто не знает.
- Вы сможете гордиться этим абсолютно бесполезным знанием.

#### Недостатки:

- Отсутствуют.

Comment: А есть более-менее реальные примеры, где эта «умопомрачительная гибкость» действительно может понадобиться? А то я тоже сижу просто эмулирую классы и не знаю, может не понимаю чего

Comment: Чёта мне кажется, что имея обыкновенное ООП, можно было бы точно так же сэмулировать протопипное. (Завести в скрытом члене `Proto`, и резольвить все обращения к публичным членам вручную.)

Comment: @andreymal *Понадобиться* эта гибкость не может: этот код никто не будет понимать, потому что изменение иерархии типов во время выполнения программы и прочая магия сломают всем мозг концептуальной сложностью. Кто-то наверняка так делает, но я бы не подходил к этому коду на расстояние пушечного выстрела.

Comment: @VladD На Тьютринг-полном языке можно сэмулировать что угодно. Классы, прототипы, вызовы методов через точку и прочее — это всё лишь синтаксический сахар. Никто не мешает сваять виртуальные таблицы методов, диспетчеризацию методов через строчки и прочее хоть на турбо паскале, хоть на ассемблере. Вопрос только в количестве букв. Все "паттерны программирования" — это латание дыр в ограниченном синтаксисе языков программирования.

Comment: @Discord: Угу, особенно с последней строчкой категорически согласен.

Answer (score -2):

Поскольку на основе прототипного наследования можно реализовать классическое, единственным его недостатком можно назвать некоторое усложнение и непривычность кода.

Comment: А на основе классического можно реализовать прототипное. И то, и другое будет костылем :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, на базе прототипного наследования можно сделать честное классическое. На базе классического можно только реализовать паттерн [Прототип](//ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29), который всё равно не то же самое, что прототипное наследование.

Comment: Не надо делать паттерн. Надо делать прототипное наследование :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov, в таком случае предлагаю отдельным ответом это продемонстрировать.

Comment: Самое главное что о достоинствах я нашел, а вот о недостатках ничего, неужели идеал?

Comment: @Abraham, мы тут как раз [в чате спорим](//chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29443420#29443420) - заходи :)

Comment: @KromStern, я всё ещё собираюсь дополнить :)

Comment: @Qwertiy: Отлично, дополните! Попробуйте сформулировать скелет основный тезисов, а мясо добавить позже. Тогда ответ будет информативным на каждом этапе.